Terraform: Create tfvars from local values
I have a data structure like the following:
locals {
  replication_tasks = {
    track_to_s3_live = {
      replication_task_id       = "track-to-s3"
      migration_type            = "full-load-and-cdc"
      replication_task_settings = file("files/s3_tracking_cdc_settings.json")
      table_mappings            = file("files/s3_tracking_table_mappings.json")
      source_endpoint_key       = "source"
      target_endpoint_key       = "s3_tracking"
    }
  }
}

From this, I'm trying to write the equivalent .tfvars file (to be used in another module). Something like:
resource "local_file" "file" {
  content  = <<EOF
replication_tasks = "${local.replication_tasks}"
EOF
  filename = "${path.module}/tasks.auto.tfvars"
}

But I get this error:
Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

Any suggestion about how to achieve this?

Not sure why you would want to do this, but to generate the desired file you can just serialize the local value:
resource "local_file" "file" {
  content  = <<EOF
replication_tasks =  ${jsonencode(local.replication_tasks)}
EOF
  filename = "${path.module}/tasks.auto.tfvars"
}


It works, thanks! For the records, I need this because, using Terragrunt, the inputs are passed using TF_VAR env variables. But the json files with table settings sometimes are very big, bigger then the OS limit

In Terraform v1.8 and later, the built-in provider named terraform (full name terraform.io/builtin/terraform) has a function encode_tfvars that knows how to produce content that is valid for Terraform's .tfvars language.
For example:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    terraform = {
      source = "terraform.io/builtin/terraform"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  replication_tasks = {
    track_to_s3_live = {
      replication_task_id       = "track-to-s3"
      migration_type            = "full-load-and-cdc"
      replication_task_settings = file("files/s3_tracking_cdc_settings.json")
      table_mappings            = file("files/s3_tracking_table_mappings.json")
      source_endpoint_key       = "source"
      target_endpoint_key       = "s3_tracking"
    }
  }
}

resource "local_file" "file" {
  content  = provider::terraform::tfvarsencode({
    replication_tasks = local.replication_tasks
  })
  filename = "${path.module}/tasks.auto.tfvars"
}

The resulting tasks.auto.tfvars file would then contain something like this:
replication_tasks = {
  track_to_s3_live = {
    replication_task_id       = "track-to-s3"
    migration_type            = "full-load-and-cdc"
    replication_task_settings = "whatever was in your file"
    table_mappings            = "whatever was in your file"
    source_endpoint_key       = "source"
    target_endpoint_key       = "s3_tracking"
  }
}


If you are using Terragrunt already then you may prefer to make use of Terragrunt's own feature for Passing outputs between units.
When using that feature, Terragrunt can automatically pass the output values from one unit into the input values of another without needing any special additional resources in the source module.
